# In full screen mode, app content is blocked by the bottom navigation bar

Tags: android, android-source

In full screen mode, the content of the application is obscured by the navigation bar at the bottom. I have the source code for the framework. Can I modify **DecorView.java** to accommodate third-party apps

Comment: You can have a try, and see what happen. Request hide navigation in onAttachedToWindow

Comment: I use setSystemUiVisibility() to hide the navigation bar in onAttachedToWindow(). When I click the video float window in the page to go to full screen, click any position in the video float window and the navigation bar will appear again.

Comment: Do you combine SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION and SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE

Comment: Yes, here's my code: setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE)

Comment: Will it be related to the Android version? The version I'm currently using is 9